# Seeking GIS web applications and front end solutions that would serve as replacement for the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder

Tags: open-source, web-apps, software-development, web-development, gis

I would like to find out if there are any Non-ESRI GIS web applications that would serve as an appropriate replacement to the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder application.

A version of the ESRI web app builder application can be customized using JavaScript with custom widgets and a dashboard showing different type of charts to display statistical information about the data displayed in the webmap. So I was hoping to find out if there are any open source or paid web application softwares that would offer similar functionality of application/widget customization.

Comment: Not much help. But I would could it in Angular and use Leaflet for the mapping. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion - specifically regarding dashboards.....Dashboard based solutions can be approached from different perspectives, often from a 'BI Dashboard, with a map'. ie: The map becomes supplemental. When you approach the solution from this perspective, the number of solutions opens up quite significantly.

Otherwise, you may also want to look at OpenLayers

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/

This solution has a large number of extensible 'widgets' (not neccassarily end user configurable, but just like ArcGIS API, uses Javascript to extent. see examples in link).